# Display posts if specific country

Tags: wp-query, ip

I'm running a simple query that displays some posts within a custom post type.

Via each post within that post type, I've added an ACF True / False checkbox. If the checkbox is ticked, I'd like that post to only appear if you're within the USA.

**Here's what I have so far:**

```
<?php // Begin loop
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

    <article>
        <?php // If within the USA
            if(get_field('usa')) {
        ?>

            <?php // Query post
                $args = array(
                    'post_type' => 'projects',
                    'posts_per_page' => 12
                );
                $get_projects = new WP_Query( $args );
                while ( $get_projects->have_posts() ) :
                $get_projects->the_post();
            ?>

                <section>
                    <header class="entry-header">
                        <?php the_title( '<h1 class="entry-title">', '</h1>' ); ?>
                    </header><!-- .entry-header -->
                    <?php the_content(); ?>
                </section>

            <?php // End query post type
                endwhile;
                wp_reset_postdata();
            ?>

        <?php } // end if

        else { // The rest of the world ?>

            <?php // Query post
                $args = array(
                    'post_type' => 'projects',
                    'posts_per_page' => 12
                );
                $get_projects = new WP_Query( $args );
                while ( $get_projects->have_posts() ) :
                $get_projects->the_post();
            ?>

                <section>
                    <header class="entry-header">
                        <?php the_title( '<h1 class="entry-title">', '</h1>' ); ?>
                    </header><!-- .entry-header -->
                    <?php the_content(); ?>
                </section>

            <?php // End query post type
                endwhile;
                wp_reset_postdata();
            ?>

        <?php } // end else ?>
    </article>
<?php endwhile; // End loop ?>
```

Am I correct in thinking that I'll need to add to the USA query by specifying a specific IP range? I couldn't find anything [via conditional](https://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags) tags on the codex.

Comment: Just a note, an IP range for an entire country is a rather large list - depending on how you structure your IPs, and people on a proxy could still access your blog from outside the USA :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at [freegeoip.net](http://freegeoip.net/). I used it like this with jquery, for example.

```
$.get( "http://freegeoip.net/json/", 'jsonp', function( data ) {
  country = data['country_code'];
  if( country == 'US' ){
    // show your content
  };
});
```